# How do I replace a burnt atmega328 with a new atmega328(bootloaded) in arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, bootloader, atmega328, safety

I have an arduino UNO with atmega 328 whose microcontroller got burnt. I bought a new atmega328. I have another working arduino with atmega8. I followed the instructions in http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoToBreadboard but I got a little confused.

I burnt the bootloader into my new atmega328 using atmega8 arduino as described in the link above. Now, can I replace my old atmega328 with this new bootloaded atmega328 to upload sketches to it? Or should I follow the steps described in the link to upload sketches?

Answer (score 2):

Once the bootloader has been burned to it, the chip can replace the one that is currently on the Arduino board. Simply follow normal DIP removal and insertion procedures to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 328p as usual (for an Arduino), once the bootloader is burned.

Background: You just used your Atmega8 as an ISP (In-System-Programmer) to get a bootloader onto your new 328p. The bootloader now enables the 328p to be programmed via serial port.

Comment: Yes - though the baud rate configured for the board chosen in the IDE  will need to match what the bootloader expects, which might or might not be the same as the original one.